# load multiple files from the same folder with multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I would like to load and concat multiple files from csvs from the same folder. I have the following code but it fails with the error
`TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`.
But I don't really understand where there should be a tuple?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool 
from itertools import repeat

def read_csv_helper(file_folder='', filename=''):
    return pd.read_csv(file_folder + filename)

def load_all_files(file_folder, file_list):
    pool = Pool()
    df_list = pool.map(read_csv_helper, zip(repeat(file_folder), file_list))
    return pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

`file_list` is something like this `'file1.dat', 'file2.dat', 'file3.dat', 'file4.dat', ..., 'filen.dat']` and `file_folder` is just the path to the folder where all these files are in.

Comment: Always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`).

Comment: Are you using Pandas just to read and concatenate all the files? Or will you be using the DataFrame. Can you get it to work without multiprocessing?

Comment: `don't really understand where there should be a tuple?` - [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are giving `.map` the wrong kind of arguments. The following simple example

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(a="a", b="b"):
    print(a, b)
    return a + b

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with Pool() as pool:
        out = pool.map(func, zip("abc", "xyz"))
    print(out)
```

does produce the same error but also prints the arguments:

- Arguments:

  ```py
  ('a', 'x') b
  ('b', 'y') b
  ('c', 'z') b
  ```
- Error:

  ```
     ...
     File "main.py", line 37, in func 
       return a + b
  TypeError: Can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
  ...
  ```

As you can see, `func` gets a tuple as 1. argument and none as the 2. one, so the default value `"b"` is used. Why is that: `Pool.map` takes the arguments directly as they are given, i.e. here tuples from `zip`.

**Fix**: Just use [`Pool.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) instead:

```py
    ...
    with Pool() as pool:
        out = pool.starmap(func, zip("abc", "xyz"))
    print(out)
```

Output this time:

```py
a x
b y
c z
['ax', 'by', 'cz']
```

`.starmap` *unpacks* the tuples from `zip` into the arguments.